# App on Server 2016 running under Framework Version: v4.0.30319 instead of 4.6?

Tags: c#

I have a full framework 4.6.2 windows service running on a Server 2016 box.  I recently moved it from using Ninject to the Microsoft extensions DI framework.  Runs fine on my local system, but when I try to run it on the server it's throwing an error, specifically something about a missing method exception.  I traced it down to my GenerateProvider method, but it's about as basic as you can get.  What caught my eye was in the error message it included this:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
```

The full error for reference:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.MissingMethodException
   at MyApp.Repository.WorkOrderRepository..ctor()
   at MyApp.Repository.ProcessingRepository..ctor()
   at MyApp.Worker..ctor(MyApp.Repository.IJobRepository)
   at MyApp.Program.Main()
```

If I'm reading that right, is it really trying to run this under the 4.0.30319 framework?  Microsoft extensions needs 4.6.1, so I imagine that'd be part of my error.  But server 2016 comes with 4.6.2, any thoughts as to why it'd try to run an app as 4.0?

Comment: Begining with .NET 4.5, *all* versions are labeled "4.0.30319". That number became totally irrelevant. Additionally, Windows 10 comes with .NET 4.6 and later updates promptly install 4.7 (wheter you want it or not). I doubt it has anything to do with the framework, but maybe with a library or some component of your program is outdated.

Comment: Ah, I was kind of wondering if it was something like that... one thing to check off the list of possible issues then I guess.